# Sliding Image Transition in java

Tags: java

I want to add a transition effect to a little 2D Hunt the Wumpus game I am writing. It has a top down view centred on the current room, in which the player can move around in. There is a door on each wall of the room, which is square.

For example, if the player walks through the North door, I want to have the room slide down, revealing the room to the North. What should I do to implement this? I really have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a movement interpolation. Basically, you want to change the vertical position of your room little by little, to create a slide effect. Optionally, you may want to apply some acceleration/deceleration effect to beautify the transition instead of using a linear approach.

Such effect is well known, and was made popular with Flash and its Tweens. A tween is an interpolation running from a starting value to an end value, in a given time. Many javascript frameworks now use tweens everywhere, like jQuery. Such transition effects are very popular.

[image]

To prevent you from reinventing the wheel, I once built a generic animation engine, the [Universal Tween Engine](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/universal-tween-engine/). You can see a demo of it [here](http://www.aurelienribon.com/universal-tween-engine/gwt/demo.html) (requires a webgl enabled browser), and here are [some](http://www.aurelienribon.com/universal-tween-engine/applets/applet-tween.html) [applets](http://www.aurelienribon.com/universal-tween-engine/applets/applet-timeline.html) with code. It was first made to create animations in android games, but it is now capable of animating everything in any java project.

The library is fully open-source under the apache2 license.

Comment: That is amazing! I can imagine you put a lot of work into that! Thanks for the quick reply, and the amazing resource. I'm sure I will be using this again, and again.

Comment: I hope it will help you. Check the wiki in the repository to get started. There is also a dedicated forum for support. I use the engine heavily in android games but also in desktop Swing applications. Check this post to get a grasp at what is possible (see the animated gif): https://plus.google.com/110022050602256925286/posts/jVBBJiZ1bkz

Answer (score 0):

You could have a center room as one image, when the player enters the north door, the north room image changes y to a smaller value so that the north room slides down, mainwhile the center room has to also slide down by changing y to a smaller value.